# java Сохранение строки со специальными символами /n

Tags: java

Попытаюсь задать свой вопрос наиболее корректно, заранее извинюсь, за возможные ошибки в изложении и терминах:

Есть переменная`String mName1 = "1\n2\n3";`

И она отображается через `System.out.println(mName1);`как

```
1
2
3
```

и это одна строка.
Но когда я пытаюсь сохранить mName1 в файл:

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false)) {

        writer.write(mName1);

        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

получаю 3 строки в файле.

**Вопрос**: как сохранить одну строку mName1 в файле со спецсимволами, причем потом считать строку из файла, в переменную mName2, с теми же возможностями как и mName1, а не этот результат  `System.out.println(mName2);`

```
1/n2/n3
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Лучше прочитайте что такое символы переноса строки.

Comment: А причём тут тэг "javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

Так три строки в файле превратятся в один объект Java.

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
```